# amplify the ac signal from fpga 3.3v to 5v with placing coupling capacitor at the input and output

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, fpga

[image: Ac signal amplifier**strong text**]

[image: a]

In the above schematic I have reduced my negative voltage in the op amp , so that I get output voltage from 0 to 5v, otherwise I am getting the voltage from negative side. please suggest me the right solution for this circuit. As I was confusing for a long period.as also ringing waveform is occuring. I need output waveform starting from 0 to 5V.(input is 3.3VAC)

Comment: The output's capacitor, C4, isn't a coupling capacitor. It forms a low-pass filter with R7.

Comment: Do you really need to use an amplifier, or do you just need to convert a 3.3V digital signal to a 5V digital signal?  A single transistor will do the job if all you need is to convert a digital signal.

Comment: yes, if i place the coupling capacitor at the output terminal, there is no proper output. it came as irregular circuit. please suggest me the proper circuit.

Comment: @JRE I need to convert ac signal from 3.3v to 5V

Comment: Look up "level shifter" for a simple solution. Ac signal implies sinusoidals, whereas your fpga is likely digital ... Yes?

Comment: Your whole system will fall apart if the signal frequency gets lower and definitely will not work for static signals. As others have stated above: look for level snifters. Also (I was a long time ago I looked at this) **check your levels**. A 3V3 CMOS output can often still drive a 5V input if the input has TTL levels. That was the main reason why 3V3 was chosen in the past: it could work with the, then established, TTL I/O levels.

Comment: I need to amplify my ac signal only from 3.3V to 5V. From FPGA, getting the ac signal of 3.3VAC(0 to 3.3). So I need output to be 5VAC(0 to 5)output.The ringing should not present. Suggest me some circuit.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum signal frequencies? Will the signal always be clock-like or does this also have to work for a data signal?